# bat file to disable ethernet adaptor and then reenable it after windows log in

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

When I log into Windows 7 I need to wait 10 seconds and then disable the Local Area Connection (ethernet adaptor) and then reenable it.

I have looked through the suggested answer: [Enable/disable wireless interface in a bat file](https://superuser.com/questions/104400/enable-disable-wireless-interface-in-a-bat-file) but that seems irrelevant as it just toggles the current state.

From what I can tell I need to include:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLED
```

but I'm unsure of the wait time or how I can have this start after Windows has successfully logged in.

What's the best approach here?

Comment: Why do you need to wait 10 seconds, disable the LAN and then re-enable it?

Comment: Tell us the underlying problem, it may be more sensible to solve that than to mess with interface.

Comment: I use 2 x TL-PA211 EOP adaptors (www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-PA211) to connect to my home modem/router. The issue is that whenever I boot up my machine, my ethernet adaptor does not automatically connect, instead I see the following: - http://i.imgur.com/weFHV.jpg – it tells me that I am connected to my usual home network plus an Unidentified network.

I then have to disable my ethernet adaptor and reenable it and then it connects to my usual home network - every time I turn the computer on. I am using the TL-PA2111 pairing application and my Ethernet drivers are up to date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a Windows Scheduled Task (`taskschd.msc` or `Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\Task Scheduler`) with a Trigger: begin the task `At log on` and in the Advanced settings delay task for `30 seconds`.  Then add an Action to `Start a program` and select your `.bat` script.

Answer (score 32):

I hope this helps

```
@echo on
timeout /t 10
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED
timeout /t 10
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLED
```

Comment: Upvoted because it's just, what I was looking for, I needed a 2 sec delay between the on and off and no initial, for when sometimes my card refuses to get a connection on startup, so I have a handy bat file on the desktop

Answer (score 3):

The logic is:
ping public ip (google dns 8.8.8.8), if the ping fails, then goto :RESTART and restart network adapter with name "LAN", after this loop again from the start (if ping is OK, then do nothing and ping in loop to check if adapter is connected to internet)

```
   @echo off 

    :LOOP
    ping 8.8.8.8
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto RESTART
    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto LOOP
    :RESTART
    netsh interface set interface "LAN" disabled
    ping -n 3 127.0.0.1
    netsh interface set interface "LAN" enabled
    ping -n 15 127.0.0.1
    goto LOOP
```

Comment: Like the logic you put in for looping!

Answer (score 1):

VERY USEFUL info here but one piece that is missing in the answers is what to enter in the "Local Area Network".  I came across this answer:

"The first step is to find the name of your wireless connection.  [Right click the WiFi symbol] > Open Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings.  It is the top line of the connection info.  Mine simply said Wi-Fi, but it could be Wireless Network Connection, etc."

BTW, if it is the LAN network card, I believe you just need to look for the name for that device.

That was key to make it work for me.

Comment: Actually,  the question is about the Ethernet network.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo off
cls 
:start
echo Choice 1
echo Choice 2
set /p choice=Yes or No?
if '%Choice%'=='1' goto :choice1
if '%Choice%'=='2' goto :choice2
echo "%Choice%" is not a valid option. Please try again. 
echo
goto start
:choice1
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" admin=Enable
goto end 
:end
pause
exit  
:choice2
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" admin=disable
goto end 
:end
pause
exit
```

Comment: I think your answer needs some explanations also for better understanding and will reflect your observations also all around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Props to the kind soul who helped setup the loop.  I changed it slightly as it refused to work on SP3.  Below is my updated disable/enable, based on the code provided above!

@echo off

```
:LOOP
ping 8.8.8.8
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto RESTART
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto LOOP
:RESTART
devcon disable "PCI\VEN_1317&*"
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1
devcon enable "PCI\VEN_1317&*"
ping -n 15 127.0.0.1
goto LOOP
```

While this does require devcon to work, this is a readily available tool from Microsoft and does a much cleaner job enabling or disabling a troublesome adapter.

http://thilina.piyasundara.org/2011/06/enabledisable-lan-interface-by-command.html shows how to do this well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

I am using this command to disable and enable the problematic WiFi network adapter;

```
> @echo on
> timeout /t 10
> netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" DISABLED
> timeout /t 2
> netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" ENABLED
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.