# Automating reconnection of internet

Tags: internet-connection, macros, wireless-adapter

I use WiFi with a router that drops my connection rarely, which is too often.  This usually happens at night, when I'm not using the computer.
I would like to automate this:

1. Detect Internet connection drop
2. Reconnect Internet

I'm thinking of using [Networx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) do detect the drop.  It has a "run [set path here]" setting, if, for example, less than XXMb is received in 15 minutes, while downloading.

For the reconnect, I'm thinking of using Auto Macro Recorder to record a manual disconnect --> connect of the WiFi, then save that as an executable/script which Networx can run.

Is there a better, surefire method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a batch file from there. I checked out that Networx setting, looks feasible.
Here is the batch file:

```
@echo on
timeout /t 10
netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" DISABLED
timeout /t 10
netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" ENABLED
```

*note: you may need to change the name of the connection to match yours

### How to create a batch file

- Right click anywhere on your desktop, hover on "new", click "Text Document"
- Open the document and add the above text to it
- Save the document and then rename it to something with .bat -
  e.g. `networkReset.bat`

Sources: [bat file to disable ethernet adaptor and then reenable it after windows log in](https://superuser.com/questions/520755/bat-file-to-disable-ethernet-adaptor-and-then-reenable-it-after-windows-log-in)

Answer (score 0):

There's usually a setting in the windows OS to 'connect automatically' if the network is available. It sounds like it might just be easier to pick up a new router. The behavior you're describing is textbook for a failing router.