# How can I create hotkey that instantly turns WiFi off?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, hotkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable/disable wireless interface in a bat file](https://superuser.com/questions/104400/enable-disable-wireless-interface-in-a-bat-file)

I need to create a hotkey that essentially instantly turns off my wireless radio card (whatever it is called), and either reconnects automatically, after a set amount of time, when pressed again OR when I press a different key.

When I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, will dissconnect me from the internet, then when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> (or <kbd>F12</kbd>) it will reconnect.

After a little research I have come up with ways such as <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, which opens Mobility centre, but that is not automatic as I still have to press "Turn Wireless Off", I am looking for a key that simply turns it on and off, as found on a lot of laptops.

Some code I found included:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#z::
 Run %windir%\system32\mblctr.exe /open
 WinWait, Windows Mobility Center
 Sleep, 300
 Send, !t
 Sleep, 1000
 WinClose, A
 Return
```

But this includes Mobility Centre again.

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that the real problem is that you're having troubles connecting to a certain WiFi and need to restart your wireless adapter for it to work?

Comment: Maybe this question could be of help to you: [Enable/disable wireless interface in a bat file](http://superuser.com/questions/104400/enable-disable-wireless-interface-in-a-bat-file)

Comment: MM i need some sort of hotkey to toggle it, not to do it through the command line, it has to be in rapid sucsession while i have a full screan program open.

Comment: @slhck i am not having problems connecting to a cirtain wifi, i am trying to toggle it while in a full screan program on a server to connect and kind of "half disconnect", when i lose connection it waits 30 seconds before kicking me, if i can turn it off then on in under 30 seconds (with a hotkey), i will be able to acheive what i want to do.

Answer (score 5):

Solved it.

```
netsh interface set interface name="Wireless Network Connection" admin = disabled  
netsh interface set interface name="Wireless Network Connection" admin = enabled
```

The first line disables it, the second enables it! Thanks for the comments.

**Update:** To find the name to be used in quotes, for Windows 7, take a look in Network and Sharing Center:

[image]

Comment: Please note, that the name 'Wireless Network Connection' may be different for different languages. So in german it is something like 'Drahtlosnetzwerkverbindung' or 'Drahtlosnetzwerkverbindung 2' ...